# MySQL table structure for wallpapers

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

**Option 1**

`wallpapers` table

> |wall_id| |wall_name| |thumbnail| |preview| |upload_date| |views| |downloads| |path_1280x800| |path_1366x768| |path_1920x1080|

**Option 2**

`wallpapers`  table

> |wall_id| |wall_name| |upload_date| |views| |downloads|

---

`wallpaper_thumnail_previews` table

> |thumbnail_preivew_id| |wall_id (F)| |thumbnail| |preview1| |preview2| |preview3|

---

`wallpaper_paths` table

> |path_id| |wall_id (F)| |path|
>
> |path| column will store all the size paths

Sample Data

```
path_id       wall_id       path
-----------   -----------   -----------
1             2             wallpaper1_1280x800.jpg
2             2             wallpaper1_1366x768.jpg
3             3             wallpaper3_1280x800.jpg
4             4             wallpaper4_1920x1080.jpg
```

Above, I've "tried" to illustrate two approaches of database design, just would like to ask for your comments/suggestions on which among the two is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave the thumbnail(s) in the main `wallpapers` table, unless there's an undefined number of thumbnails per wallpaper.  I assume instead that you have, say, a 64x64 small thumbnail and a 200x200 large thumbnail; some small defined set.

I would push the paths to the actual images into a separate table, as illustrated in your second proposal.  You probably will want to provide wallpapers at different resolutions in the future (for the latest mobile device, say), and such an easily-anticipated situation shouldn't require a DDL change.  Note that this table should have `width` and `height` fields.  I hope you're not seriously suggesting storing multiple paths in `path`!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! No, I'm not storing multiple paths in just one field of `path`, every size has its own row. For width and height I'm using a different table and referencing it with `wall_id` as well, would that be good?

Comment: So the grain in your `wallpapers` table is not an image, but an image at a particular resolution?  In that case there's no need for a separate table, you can store the path to that one image in a field in this table.  That doesn't sound efficient to me, though; surely there's information you'll want to track per image, like author?

Comment: amm its not the actual image stored in the table, just the paths for different sizes. For the author/creator of the image, I was thinking to put it in the `wallpapers` table instead of in the `wallpaper_paths` table, is that good?

Comment: I've added some sample data for reference.

Comment: I would recommend putting any information specific to the wallpaper itself in the `wallpapers` table, certainly.  A second table with one record per image makes sense, as you can reasonably expect that you'll want to support additional resolutions in the future.  As for thumbnails, if you already have a table with a grain of { Wallpaper, Resolution }, you might as well store thumbnails here too.